# Driving a 12V DC small pump with a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, switches, snubber

I need to drive a small immersion pump with a 5V output of a microcontroller. I found easy to find this mosfet: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/RFP30N06LE.pdf
By looking at the datasheet looks like they don't use any Snubber network while driving an inductive load... Is this just a simplification or this device can do without?

Comment: MOSFET datasheets rarely go into such things. It’s up to the designer of the circuit to ensure you are within the specifications.

Comment: In the datasheet, I see only a test circuit that is used for measuring some parameters. There is no application circuit given.

Comment: Safest to add a flyback diode across the inductive load to protect your FET.  If you add it, you don't need to do any analysis about whether you need it or not :-)